# Tab bar disappears after segue is performed

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uistoryboard

I made an application using a UITabBarController where the hierarchy looks like this:
[image: This is my storyboard]
The problem I can't figure out how to solve is that when I segue from "Recent Searches" to "Smashtag", the bottom tab bar disappears as if the new MVC is covering it.
How can I make it so that I can segue from "Recent Searches" to "Smashtag" without hiding the bottom tab bar?
Thank you in advance

EDIT: when I say "segue to 'Smashtag'" I mean "segue to the navigation controller which contains 'Smashtag'"

Comment: You *probably* want to Segue from `Recent Searches` **to** `SmashTag` directly, *not* to another Navigation Controller. Give that a try (make it a Show/Push segue).

Comment: I was sure that I had tried that before... but it works!! Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to segue from one tab of the tab bar controller to another using a ["push" segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html) while you're inside a `UINavigationController`. This causes the navigation controller to push the Smashtag view controller onto its own stack, ignoring the tab bar.

What you can do is programmatically show the other tab of the tab bar by change its `selectedIndex`:

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```

This code should go into whatever action causes the presented view controllers to change (e.g. pressing a button).